# Does the python C extension copy python objects directly, or modify pointers?

Tags: python, c

When parsing a python object, such as through PyArg_ParseTuple("s",&addr), does `addr` just get modified to the string portion of the python object's address, or is there a memory allocation call that goes somewhere? If the memory is copied, is there any way to avoid this? For context, I'm trying to pass large buffers from python into C quickly, and would like to avoid unnecessary memory copies.

Comment: Typically, there is no copying, unless the object you pass from Python is not of the same type than the one you want to receive, and that some conversion must happen (e.g., you pass a unicode string from python but receive it as `char *` on the C side). If you really want full control, create a dummy object for raw data interchange.

Comment: Thanks! I still haven't quite figured out whether or not malloc'ing happens in the case of a string, but I figured I can just pass in the "id" of the function to C, which corresponds to the pointer to the python object and then use more Python api functions on that.

Comment: Note: After using the id() function and parsing a long instead of passing the string, I saw a 20 percent performance increase, which I would assume is python overhead due to bcopying the string.

Comment: I created a c function which takes a string ('s'), and modify the first character. Then in python I call the funciton and the `str` object is modified (despite it is "inmutable"). So clearly the is no buffer copying there.